# How to change the font color of a list in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

So, I'm trying to make these nav-links of mine to change its color whenever I click a button, but it does not seem to work.

```
   <ul class="nav-links">
         <li id = link><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li id = link><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
         <li id = link><a href="#">About</a></li>
         <li id = link><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
   </ul>
   <label class="toggle">
         <input type="checkbox" class="check">
         <span class="slider" onclick="dark()"></span>
   </label>
```

I tried doing this script but it still doesn't work

```
  const text = document.querySelector(".logo");
  const body = document.querySelector("body");
  const banner = document.querySelector(".L-banner");
  const navLinks = document.getElementById("#link");
  function dark(){
      text.style.color = "#fff";
      body.style.background = "#000";
      banner.style.color = "#fff";

      for(var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++){
        navLinks[i].style.color = "#fffff";
      }
  }
```

Comment: Did you attach event listener?

Comment: `navLinks = document.getElementById("#link");` ... 1. id's MUST be unique, so havng more than one makes no sense. 2. getElementById returns a SINGLE element, 3. getElementById accepts the actual `id` ...i.e. `link` not `#link` - perhaps you meant `const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll("#link");`

Comment: omg, thank you i didnt realize it, this is very helpful!

Comment: and it is working now so Thank youu!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't give multiple elements the same ID, and [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) only selects a single element.

To select all the links, you can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', changeColor);
function changeColor() {
    const links = [...document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li a')];
    links.forEach(link => link.style.color = "cornflowerblue");
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-links">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Contacts</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<button id="button">Change link color</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change it to this

```
      const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll("#link a");
```

also don't forget to fix  html

```
<ul class="nav-links">
      <li id="link"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li id="link"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      <li id="link" ink><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li id="link" ink><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
```